# how can I perform clustering on a dataset including time series and discrete point variables?

Tags: time-series, cluster-analysis, distance, unsupervised-learning, dtw

I am trying to perform clustering on a dataset including time series (e.g. sensor recording over a few seconds) and discrete valued variables (e.g. age). I have already tried PCA to combine the original variables and then standard clustering which effectively solves the problem of having time series and discrete valued variables. I would now like to perform time-series clustering using dynamic time warping (DTW) distance but I am not sure how I can incorporate the discrete valued variables.

My first attempt was to calculate DTW distance for the time-series variables, Euclidean distance for the discrete variables and then combine these distances into a single similarity matrix. The issue is that, because of the way DTW is calculated (sum of all the Euclidean distances between optimal matched points in two time series), the scale of the DTW distance is much larger than that of the discrete variables, even after standardising the variables. If I then apply clustering on the resulting distance matrix, the discrete variables would be pretty meaningless, which is not the case in the real world.

I am trying to find similar examples in the literature and cases in all the Stacks but I've not been very lucky. I thought about:

- scaling the DTW distance by the length of the series but that can be a bit tricky with time series with different lengths and on initial attempts, it seems it shrinks the distance in the time series variables a lot.
- converting the discrete variable into a time series of constant values but I am not sure this is a great idea either.

Does anyone know of any examples or has anyone got any clever ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to leverage any generic stock ticker analysis to get what you want. Here is a link that shows a simple time series analysis of stock data, as well as a few clustering exercises.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Clustering%20-%20Historical%20Stock%20Prices.ipynb

[image: https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Clustering%20-%20Historical%20Stock%20Prices.ipynb]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]